# How to calculate the Lie derivative for 2-forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative

I know how to calculate Lie derivative for one-forms I use this formula:

$$\mathcal{L}_X\alpha = \left(X^j\frac{\partial \alpha_i}{\partial \phi^j} + \alpha_j \frac{\partial X^j}{\partial \phi^i}\right)d\phi^i.$$

But how to calculate Lie derivative for 2-forms or 3-forms ? I think we can write for example a 2-form like a wedge product of 1-forms and then use formula:
$$\mathcal L_X\omega_{1}\wedge\omega_{2}=(\mathcal L_X\omega_{1})\wedge\omega_{2}+\omega_{1}\wedge(\mathcal L_X\omega_{2})$$
But I tried and failed.
Can someone explain me how to calculate Lie derivative for 2-forms and 3-forms ?

I wish to have an explicit formula or an explicit algorithm please.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1699500/173147

Answer (score 4):

You can use Cartan's homotopy formula:

$$\mathcal{L}_X\omega=d(\iota_X\omega)+\iota_Xd\omega,$$ where $d$ denotes the exterior derivative, $\iota_X$ denotes the interior product, and $X$ is a vector field.

EDIT- As for the interior multiplication:

Explicitly, if $X$ is a smooth vector field on a manifold $M$ and $\omega\in\Omega^k(M),$ then $\iota_X \omega$ is a $k-1$ form defined by $$(\iota_X\omega)(X_2,\cdots, X_k)=\omega(X,X_2,\cdots, X_k),$$ for any smooth vector fields $X_2,\cdots, X_k$.

Comment: we have 6 days since we started the differential geometry and there are many notations you can write explicitly who is: $\iota_X\omega$ $\iota_Xd\omega$

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question but how is $\omega(X,X_2,\cdots, X_k)$ definited and in your formula: $\mathcal{L}_X\omega=d(\iota_X\omega)+\iota_Xd\omega,$ $\iota_X\omega$ where is applied?

Comment: $\omega$ is an arbitrary $k$-form, so it eats $k$ vector fields. As for your second question, interior multiplication is defined by how it acts on vector fields.  In Cartan's formula, we enter a $k$-form get back a $k$-form, so it is defined by then acting on $k$ vector fields.